# IMAP IP address log?

Tags: ip, imap, logging

I have qmail and can I see from what IP addresses was access to my account?
I'm using webmail (imap) and is there any chance that I can see access IP addresses and see is there any misuse of my account?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you run the server?  If it is a webmail account you could go look at your apache logs easily. AFAIK Qmail isn't a imap server so you would need to tell us what the actual IMAP server is for us to point you to the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will indeed depend largely on your IMAP server -- something qmail doesn't provide. 
For courrier-imap (which is common with qmail, it is myself what I run) you may grep your logs for 'imapd' and 'imapd-ssl'.

Where the log entries go also largely depend on your syslog configuration, but if it is not particularly configured to log to a different stream for your imap server, it should be in the default syslog.

You might want to investigate /var/log.

This might be of some help in figuring out where your imap log files are:

`# find /var/log | xargs grep imap`

Mine are kept in `/var/log/mail.log`, which is how I configured it.

For courrier imap, for instance, the LOGIN entries look like this

`Jul  2 17:23:15 servername imapd-ssl: LOGIN, user=username@host.com, ip=[::ffff:192.168.148.120], protocol=IMAP`

Where, of course, `username@host.com` is the account name. I use vpopmail, your mileage may vary. But here we see that the IP address is the 8th column (separated by space(s)) in the log.

To easily compile a list of IPs that accessed your account with courrier-imap, you could do something like this:
`# grep "LOGIN" mail.log | grep "username@host.com" | awk '{ print $8 }' | sort | uniq
ip=[::ffff:172.16.64.XX],
ip=[::ffff:172.16.64.XY],
ip=[::ffff:172.16.64.YZ],
ip=[::ffff:209.5.XX.XX],
ip=[::ffff:24.114.XZ.XY],
ip=[::ffff:24.114.XX.XY],
ip=[::ffff:24.114.YY.ZZ],`

Of course replace the expression in grep, the log file, the username and the column field in awk with ones fitting of your imap server.